# DAG Running stop once it reach 50 successfully

Tags: airflow

I am using latest AirFlow. I ran a dag file which just executes print and sleeps command for 10 seconds.

Once that dag complete 50 successful runs it automatically stoped. When I restart the web server , scheduler and worker then it again runs for another 50. I did this way 2 times and the same result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with the schedule.

Most likely reason is  the schedule is made of **Catchup** or Backfill task with specific start_date  and  **end_date**  parameters .

for more details https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/dag-run.html

Comment: dag = DAG(
    '900',
    default_args=default_args,
#    max_active_runs=1,
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
#    start_date=datetime(2015, 12, 1),
    schedule_interval='* * * * *',
)

Comment: I dont have a start or end date.

Comment: I am not sure about catchup topic. Can you recommend any link with a good example?

Comment: what is  schedule_interval='* * * * *' expression means

Comment: schedule_interval = Frequency of dag running.

Comment: Hi check the schedule /Frequency  dag three will be 50 run from (1 dec 2015,)